# Jquery / Javascript - most efficient way to build a select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and trying to tune my select menu builder to run much quicker.

I was using each and append, however I've since switched to a standard for loop and currently trying to convert my options from using append to concatenated string appended to my select option using .html(). I seem to be at a loss trying to convert my var option object back to an html string. Could someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong.

```
$.selectMenuBuilder = function(json) {
    var myselect = $("#myselect");    
    var list = "<option value=\"\">> Select Account Number</option>";

    var l= json.funding.length;
    for(var i=0;i<l; i++) { 
       var funding = json.funding[i];    
       var option = $("<option value=\"" + funding.id + "\">" + funding.accountNumber + "</option>")

       if(someLogic) {
           option.attr("selected", "selected");
       }

       //Having trouble here converting option object back to html. 
       list += option.html();
   }

   list += "<option value=\"addnew\">+ New Account Number</option>";

   myselect .html(list);
}
```

Comment: Just a typo used in this simplified example. My actual select menu fields all come from my json object.

Comment: You dont need jQuery for the option, but if you do want to use it, create the object outside of the loop and just modify the id/value property inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can totally do away with using jQuery for creating the `option` elements (unless theres some other untold reason you're using it).

i.e. Instead of

```
var option = $("<option value=\"" + funding.id + "\">" + funding.accountNumber + "</option>")
if(someLogic) option.attr("selected", "selected");
```

You can do:

```
list += "<option value=\"" + funding.id + "\" "+ (someLogic?'selected':'') +">" + funding.accountNumber + "</option>"
```

---

Secondly, `$(option).html()` will return the `innerHTML` of the *option* element, not including the *option tag name*. For doing this in a cross-browser fashion, you can wrap the option in an outer element and use its `innerHTML` instead.

i.e.

`$(option).wrap('<select/>').parent().html()` will give you what you want.

Comment: shouldn't html encode values that you're concatenating into an html string?

Comment: @Techfoobar, would pure javascript run much faster than using jquery append?

Comment: @George - I mean html encoding like < to & l t ;

Comment: @George - In your particular case, jQuery is simply not needed for adding the options. And native always runs faster than any interpreted library code. So is best (and faster) to just use native strings to form the entire HTML and append it to the DOM in one go.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the `for` loop but want something that looks a bit cleaner, try this:

```
function menuBuilder( json ) {

  var list = [],
      $select = $('#myselect'),
      i = 0, 
      l = json.funding.length,
      funding;

  for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
    funding = json.funding[ i ];
    list.push(
      '<option '+ somelogic ? 'selected' : ''+' value='+ funding.id +'>'+
        funding.accountNumber +
      '</option>'
    );
  }

  $select.append(
    '<option>Select Account Number</option>'+
    list.join('') +
    '<option value="addnew">New Account Number</option>'
  );

}
```

Comment: using a javascript native array/stack and join/concatenating only once at the end will likely be the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can create elements more efficiently like this:

```
$.selectMenuBuilder = function (json) {
    var myselect = $("#myselect");

    var l = json.funding.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var funding = json.funding[i];

        var opt = $("<option/>", {
            value: funding.id,
            html: funding.accountNumber,
            selected: somelogic ? true : false //Pre-select option
        });

        myselect.append(opt);

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm under the understanding that append is very slow. I have  efficiently populate at a very extreme case, up to 1000 select menus. Chances are near 100% that will never happen in production, but a requirement set forth by management.

Answer (score 0):

efficiency with pure JavaScript

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2gkp/1/)

```
selectMenuBuilder = function(json) {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("myselect"),
        listItem = document.createElement("option"),
        l = json.funding.length,
        someLogic = false; // placeholder

    listItem.innerText = "> Select Account Number";
    myselect.appendChild(listItem);

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var funding = json.funding[i];
        var listItem = document.createElement("option");

        if (someLogic) {
            listItem.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
        }
        listItem.setAttribute("value", funding.id);
        listItem.innerText = funding.accountNumber;

        myselect.appendChild(listItem);
    }

    listItem = document.createElement("option")
    listItem.setAttribute("value", "addnew");
    listItem.innerText = "+ New Account Number";
    myselect.appendChild(listItem);
}
```